# Converting an HTML string into a pdf using iText

Tags: java, itext

I am creating a PDF report using itext 2.1.7. Using a `ColumnText` object, I am adding paragraphs, tables cells and images etc. 
Now I want to add an HTML string in the columnText object. How can this be done?

**This is my code snippet**

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
Rectangle pagesize = reader.getPageSize(1);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest1));
ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(stamper.getOverContent(1));
columnText.setSimpleColumn(45, 70,685,710);
PdfPTable heading_table = new PdfPTable(1);
heading_table.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
Image image = Image.getInstance(headingfilename);
heading_table.addCell(image);
columnText.addElement(heading_table);

String str = "<html><body> This is my Project </body></html>";
columnText.setSimpleColumn(45, 70,685,710);
//System.out.println("THe column size is : " + columnText.getLastX());
int pagecount = 1;
Rectangle rectPage2 = new Rectangle(45, 70,685,710); 
int statusss = columnText.go();
System.out.println("The Status is: " + statusss);
int n = 0;
while (ColumnText.hasMoreText(statusss)) {
    n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    statusss = triggerNewPage(stamper, reader, pagesize, columnText, rectPage2, ++pagecount);
    System.out.println(statusss);
}

onEndChange(stamper, n, "Sample Report","Sample only, not for distribution");
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

How to add this `str` in the `Columntext` object?

Comment: Not only are you spelling my name incorrectly (I'm Lowagie, not Lowaige), you are asking for functionality that didn't exist in 2009. You should upgrade to a more recent version for that *technical* reason, but there is also a *legal* reason. iText 2.1.7 contains code we weren't allowed to release as MPL/LGPL. We removed all known copies of iText 2.1.7 from the servers we controlled **and so should you.** Read [Can iText 2.1.7 / iTextSharp 4.1.6 or earlier be used commercially?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. You'll find the community and most people quite helpful.

But now to your question: I don't fully understand it. Do you "only" want to add some html string or do you want to use html formatting?
To print out some string (html or not):

```
    ...
    columnText.addElement(heading_table);

    Phrase str = new Phrase("<html><body> This is my Project </body></html>");
    columnText.addElement(str);
    ...
```

On a general note: 
Please be as precise in your question as possible and 2nd create a [mcvp](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Your code doesn't work since the methode `triggerNewPage`or `onEndChange` etc. are not part of your code.